# Netmiko : connecting to a router, Invalid parameter ^

Tags: networking, automation, cisco, netmiko

i was trying to connect to a router and to just get the result of a one command the code is below :

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler 

router = { "device_type": "xxxx", 
"host": "xxxx", 
"username": "xxxx", 
"password": "xxxx", 

} 

command = "show arp all" 

net_connect= ConnectHandler(**router)
output = net_connect.send_command(command) 

print(output)
```

and i get this error  ' Error: Invalid parameter ^ ' i don't undrestand where is the problem !

Can someone figure out the error please !

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the command itself. There is no `all` in the command. Please consider sending `show arp` or `show ip arp` without <strike>`all`</strike>. Check out this [link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/asr9000/software/asr9k_r4-0/addr_serv/command/reference/ir40asrbook_chapter2.html). You can also add `"session_log": "router.log"` to the router's dictionary and find the invalid parameter message in the `router.log` file.

> The log file shows you what is happening in the CLI on the device.

Try doing something like:

```py
router = {
    "device_type": "xxxx",
    "host": "xxxx",
    "username": "xxxx",
    "password": "xxxx",
    "session_log": "router.log"  # <--- this line
}

cmd = "show arp"  # or "show ip arp"

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**router)
arp_output = net_connect.send_command(cmd)
net_connect.disconnect() # to clear the vty line when done

print(arp_output)
```

Answer (score 0):

One another approach is to send "terminal length 0" command before sending "show arp all" command. You should also send "show arp all" command with netmiko timing method, so that all outputs should be collected till the bottom line.

```
command = "show arp all" 
net_connect= ConnectHandler(**router)
net_connect.send_command("terminal length 0")
output = net_connect.send_command_timing(command) <<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Just a sample code helps to get "show interface description" data.

```
asr9k = {
    "host" : "10.10.10.10",
    "username" :"admin",
    "password" :"admin",
    "port" : 22,
    "device_type" : "cisco_xr",
 }

con = ConnectHandler(**asr9k)
con.enable()

data_to_parse = con.send_command_timing('show interface description')
```